# ERROR Decimal Number VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, floating-point, decimal

It's not working for some reason.

```
Imports System.Math

Public Class Form1

Dim TheWholeNumber As Double
Dim TheRoundedNumber As Double

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

'The Whole Number.
TheWholeNumber = Math.Truncate(Val(Tx_TheNumber.Text))
Tx_TheWholeNumber.Text = TheWholeNumber.ToString

'The Decimal Number
Tx_TheDecimalNumber.Text = (Val(Tx_TheNumber.Text).ToString - Val(Tx_TheWholeNumber.Text)).ToString
```

So I input 9876543210.0123456789 into Tx_TheNumber Textbox.

It has no problem giving me the Truncated number in Tx_TheWholeNumber TextBox.
It is displaying '9876543210 in Tx_TheDecimalNumber TextBox.

But the problem is : Tx_TheDecimalNumber.Text is showing 0.0123405456542969

I'm like.. whaaat? How hard is it to subtract whole number from whole number..
and that's what you're giving me..?

It's The Whole number subtracting The number with the digits after the decimal place, which is Tx_TheNumber. I honestly don't know what's going on, seeing that if you did that, the result would be the number after the decimal place.

Math.Truncate is a Double. Decimal.Truncate is a decimal. So.. Can someone help me with this? I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Val(Tx_TheTextBox.Text) converts the String to a Double. I use it a lot. Never have any problems with Val giving me wrong answers when I calculate stuff. I built an Ohm's law calculator with it, and my numbers match up with Ohm's law calculators online. So..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the fact that you are using `Val` which returns a `Double` not a `Decimal` floating point arithmetic is inherintly error prone.

The solution? Cast to a Decimal data type and subtract these:

Use decimal data types

```
Dim TheWholeNumber As Decimal
Dim TheRoundedNumber As Decimal
```

Convert to Decimal instead of using `Val`

```
    'The Whole Number.
    TheWholeNumber = Math.Truncate(CDec(Tx_TheNumber.Text))
    Tx_TheWholeNumber.Text = TheWholeNumber.ToString

    'The Decimal Number
    Tx_TheDecimalNumber.Text = (CDec(Tx_TheNumber.Text) - CDec(Tx_TheWholeNumber.Text)).ToString
```

Note: you also have introduced issues by converting your numeric data type to a string and subtracting using this. Using `Option Strict On` will prevent these types of errors from compiling so you should use it

Comment: AWESOME !! Thanks. I'll use CDec and use Decimal from now on.. I was using Decimal before, but changed my code. etc.

Comment: Don't forget to Switch Option Strict On (and set it to default On for all new projects) this will help you!

Comment: Which can be found here..
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/c553zwz0(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Which can be found here..
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/c553zwz0(v=vs.100).aspx

STEP : 1
http://oi67.tinypic.com/2aj4a5x.jpg

STEP : 2 & 3
http://oi64.tinypic.com/35cj23a.jpg


Thanks. It was turned Off, & I turned it On.

Comment: Also don't forget `Tools>Options>Projects and Solutions>VB Defaults>Option Strict On` as this ensures any new projects have it switched on by default